Finding literature with quantum tomography during a measurement to "see" the wave function collapse
I was at a journal club some time around 2020 where we discussed a paper that I am trying to find again. The claim was that it had experimentally shown that wave function collapse was not "instant" by doing quantum tomography on a system being measured, and seeing the system go continuously from a superposition to an eigenstate of the measured basis. It probably involved some kind of weak measurement.
Can you point me to any literature performing such an experiment?
Candidates I have looked at so far, which do not seem to be the paper I am looking for, are

Experimental proof of nonlocal wavefunction collapse for a single particle using homodyne measurements
Complete characterization of post-selected quantum statistics using weak measurement tomography
Strong Measurements Give a Better Direct Measurement of the Quantum Wave Function
Testing Spontaneous Wave-Function Collapse Models on Classical Mechanical Oscillators


You may be thinking of this paper, which concerns not measurement per se but quantum "jumps" between energy levels in an artificial atom.  The jump is inferred from a break in the fluorescence of the three-level "atom", which I think would count as, as you say, some kind of weak measurement. https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-019-1287-z
